# Default SSH username doesn't match $USER value in macOS

Tags: macos, ssh, macos-highsierra

**Note:** I managed to get this working, now I'm trying to figure out why there's a discrepancy.

I recently enabled remote access on my laptop running macOS High Sierra.  However, I initially had trouble ssh-ing in.  When I ran `ssh localhost` it would prompt me for a password which it always rejected.  When I ran `ssh ${USER}@localhost` my SSH keys kicked in and I logged in immediately.

After turning up the verbosity, I noticed that `ssh localhost` was attempting to authenticate as `firstname.lastname`, but my user account and `$USER` variable are `firstnamelastname` (without a dot).  This explains why `ssh ${USER}@localhost` worked and the other didn't.

So what gives?  Why is ssh trying to authenticate with something other than `$USER`?  Where is it getting the dotted form from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `ssh localhost` is using a different username from the one in `$USER` there might be a line overriding the User in your ssh configuration file.

Check in `~/.ssh/config` and `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

---

You can also try to add the following line in your `~/.ssh/config` (create the file if it doesn't exists):

```
User firstnamelastname
```

Then, restart `ssh`:

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

and check again your ssh default user name with verbose mode:

```
ssh -v localhost
```

You should see a line like this:

```
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:22 as 'firstnamelastname'
```

(That is, the one you defined in your `~/.ssh/config`)

Comment: Bah, silly me.  That's exactly what it was.  Not sure what past me was thinking when I put it there.